# FileReadingMessageSource vs Metadatastore

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm wondering how to prevent that multiple instances of a particular DSL integration flow will consume the same files concurrently. I'm using **FileReadingMessageSource** in the beginning of the the flow so it is my "file watcher" in this case... Would be one of those **Metadatastore** an option? If so, how can I attach it into the flow? I have a **GenericSelector** after reading the files in order to filter out some unwanted file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileReadingMessageSource` uses an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` by default to prevent reading duplicates. But it is in-memory. So, if you'd like to survive an application restart and don't want to see already processed files, you are free to configure that `FileReadingMessageSource` with a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` supplied with some shared `ConcurrentMetadataStore` implementation.

You also can compose this filter with others like `RegexPatternFileListFilter`.
See more info in docs about `ChainFileListFilter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/file.html#file-reading

Comment: Thanks, I'll set this up tomorrow first thing and let you know.